# Should I share temp tables across nested stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am currently trying to clean up some stored procedures. There are about 20 of them that look very similar and do many of the same things, but take in slightly different parameters and filter data differently.

For the most part, all of the stored procs start by loading some data in to one or two table variables (which is generally where the procs differ). After that, all of the code for each sproc is more or less the same. They perform some logging and apply some additional common filters.

I wanted to at least turn the common pieces in to stored procs so that the code would be easier to read and we wouldn't have to open 20 procedures to update the same line of sql, but the use of table variables prevents it. We are using Sql Server 2005, and to my knowledge we cannot used table valued parameters in our stored procedures.

We could, however, change all of the table variables to temp tables and reference them in the new common stored procedures. I am assuming that is a fairly common practice, but wanted to know if it was actually a good idea.

In the nested stored procedures, should I assume that a temp table has already been created elsewhere and just query off of it? I can test whether or not the table exists, but what if it doesn't? Is there a good alternative to this in 2005? Is it confusing for other developers who open one of the nested stored procs and see a temp table that is created elsewhere? Do I just need to add lots of informative comments?

Comment: In your nested proc; to be sure, you can check whether table exist or not. If not exist then `RAISERROR` with some error message. Since, you are using SS2005, #temptable would be the option you have. Commenting your code for ease of readability is never a bad practice.

Comment: Is there any sort of naming convention for procedures that are intended to be nested and shouldn't be called on their own? I know should add comments, but I have seen many instances where code changes but nobody updates the comment to reflect it. That is something we can manage with good practices, of course, but anything to help readability and consistency is welcome. I guess temp tables are probably my ONLY option at this point.

Comment: talking about naming convention; follow any convention that fits better in your organization (I just gave a proper name to the SP that will reflect the purpose of the SP). If code changes is happening then changing the comment accordingly is the developer responsibility. Other than this, whatever you are doing looks correct to me.

Comment: Cool, I was hoping that was the case. Thanks for you input, Rahul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nested proc; to be sure, you can check whether table exist or not. If not exist then `RAISERROR` with some error message. Since, you are using SS2005, `#temptable` would be the option you have. Commenting your code for ease of readability is never a bad practice.

Talking about naming convention; follow any convention that fits better in your organization (I just gave a proper name to the SP that will reflect the purpose of the SP). If code changes is happening then changing the comment accordingly is the developer responsibility. Other than this, whatever you are doing looks correct to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Thought of making that an answer but got it working by the comment conversation. Moreover, there are many such comment only answer in SO (which personally I don't like cause that have very less possibility to be useful for a future reader(s)) but have never seen anyone proposing that to make an answer likewise you did (which I really appreciate). Not sure what's the actual convention I should follow (never make a comment only answer OR what?). Anyways, pulled of my comment and made it an answer. Thanks for suggesting that. Now give a +1 ... LOL :)